# XSL - How to select innerhtml of a node

Tags: xslt, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have following html snippet:

```
<div class="rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget">
  <div g:type="AverageStarRating" g:secondaryurls="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997" g:decorateusingsecondary="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997" g:groups="maps" g:rating_override="2.998000" class="rsw-stars ">   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get innerhtml of the first div. The expected result is:

```
<div g:type="AverageStarRating" g:secondaryurls="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997" g:decorateusingsecondary="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997" g:groups="maps" g:rating_override="2.998000" class="rsw-stars ">     </div>
```

How can I do that? Ex `<xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget']/html()" />`
This will not work because there's no html() function. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you searching for the correct XPath expression?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath-expression solution. :)

Comment: Is it pure end-to-end Xml or Html as parsed by Html Agility Pack? Do you have a piece of code to see what you're exactly using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[@class='rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget']/node()
```

This selects any node (element, text-node, processing instruction or comment-node) that is a child of any element selected by the expression `//div[@class='rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget']`.

**XSLT verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//div[@class='rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget']/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be wellformed):

```
<div class="rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget">
    <div xmlns:g="g:g"
        g:type="AverageStarRating"
        g:secondaryurls="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997"
        g:decorateusingsecondary="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997"
        g:groups="maps" g:rating_override="2.998000" class="rsw-stars "></div>
 </div>
```

**selects and outputs exactly the wanted nodes**:

```
    <div xmlns:g="g:g" g:type="AverageStarRating"
 g:secondaryurls="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997" 
 g:decorateusingsecondary="http://maps.google.com/?cid=12948004443906002997" 
 g:groups="maps" g:rating_override="2.998000" class="rsw-stars "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the posted fragment is the complete document in the `doc` variable:

```
var outerDivNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/div");
var innerDivText = outerDivNode.InnerHtml;
```

Alternatively:

```
var innerDivNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/div/dev");
var innerDivText = innerDivNode.OuterHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, XSLT does not have an `html()` method. Your select statement is just about right. If you remove the `/html()` you'll have selected the `<div>` element you're and using `<xsl:value-of>` will output all of the node's contents.

If you're using thsi in the context of the HtmlAgilityPacl (as you've tagged it) then follow Oded's approach (with a slightly modified select):

```
var outerDivNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='rsw-pp rsw-pp-widget']");
var innerDivText = outerDivNode.InnerHtml;
```